# \centering and showexpl

Tags: horizontal-alignment, showexpl

Consider the following MWE, where the table is clearly not centered by `\centering`. Actually, moving `\centering` *outside* the `table` environment give the desired output, but that's no good...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{This is a fairly simple table.}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
        a & e \\ \hline
        b & f \\ \hline
        c & g \\ \hline
        d & h \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: removed previous comments since I had misread the question. Sorry!

Comment: @dcmst Adding `\par` after `\end{tabular}` works, but why? I never do that when writing...

Comment: A blank line works too. I always put the caption after the table, and that fixes it too.

Comment: @marczellm In scientific reports, the caption should be above the table, but below the figure ;-) But I still don't understand why I need the blank line, or the `\par`, in the `LTXexample` environment.

Comment: that's because of the inner working of `centering`, that needs a paragraph ending before the group ends. That's why you usually use centering in enviroments. Btw, disregard my suggestion, since your goal is to show the code that produces a centered tabular, and your code does that without LTXexample (I did not realize that)

Comment: @Holene `\centering` _always_ needs a following `\par` try `{\centering abc}` however `end{table}` normally adds it implictly. the fact that it doesn't here is probably a bug.

Comment: `showexpl` surely needs to redefine `table` (else it would float) and probably the new definition is missing a `\par`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a package bug but easy to fix, the redefinition of table and figure should end with `\par` not with nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\SX@@preset{%
  \renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{\SX@eat@version}%
  \renewcommand\usepackage[2][]{\SX@eat@version}%
  \renewenvironment{document}{}{}%
  \renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{\def\@captype{figure}}{\par}%<<<<<<
  \renewenvironment{table}[1][]{\def\@captype{table}}{\par}%<<<<<<<<
  \renewcommand\cite[1][]{}%
  \let\tableofcontens\relax \let\listoffigures\relax
  \let\listoftables\relax \let\printindex\relax
  \let\listfiles\relax \let\nofiles\relax
  \let\index\@gobble \let\label\@gobble
  \let\bibliography\@gobble
  \let\pagestyle\@gobble \let\thispagestyle\@gobble
  %%\let\immediate\relax \let\write\@gobbletwo
  %%\let\closeout\@gobble \let\@@input\@gobble
  \renewcommand\marginpar[2][]{}%
  \renewcommand\footnote[2][]{}%
  \let\@footnotetext\@gobble
  %%\abovedisplayskip=\z@
  %%\abovedisplayshortskip=\z@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{This is a fairly simple table.}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
        a & e \\ \hline
        b & f \\ \hline
        c & g \\ \hline
        d & h \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```