# Create a LTXexample environment ala figure*

Tags: two-column, showexpl

How can I patch `LTXexample` to have the behavior of span two columns when used as `LTXexample*` (like using `figure*` in a `twocolumn` mode document)?

Thus, the following code doesn't work due to the `figure*`, as it will span two columns, but the `LTXexample` will span only one.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{LTXexample}[pos=b]

\begin{figure*}[bt]%prefer bottom (b) and then top (t)
\centering
\subfloat[Case I]{%<- this stops spurious white spaces
  \rule{5cm}{5cm}
  \label{fig:first_case}
}%
\subfloat[Case II]{%
  \rule{5cm}{6cm}
  \label{fig:second_case}
}
\caption{Caption example.}
\label{fig:twocol}
\end{figure*}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I borrowed a line from [David Carlisle's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149896/centering-and-showexpl) answer to fix an apparent bug in the figure environment, which (I think) was causing an outer par mode error. I then simply switched to `\onecolumn` mode before your example, then back to `\twocolumn` mode after.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{subfig}

\makeatletter
    \renewenvironment{figure*}[1][]{\def\@captype{figure}}{\par}%<<<<<<
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\onecolumn

\begin{LTXexample}[pos=b]
{\begin{figure*}[bt]%prefer bottom (b) and then top (t)
\centering
\subfloat[Case I]{%<- this stops spurious white spaces
    \rule{5cm}{5cm}
    \label{fig:first_case}
}%
\subfloat[Case II]{%
    \rule{5cm}{6cm}
    \label{fig:second_case}
}
\caption{Caption example.}
\label{fig:twocol}
\end{figure*}}
\end{LTXexample}

\twocolumn

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I needed to show the example of using `figure*`. The issue is that I have a two column document, so I would like the figure and the code to appear both spanning the two columns.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your comment.  See if this suits your needs. If not, sorry. I've exhausted my limited knowledge.